# SQLite how to get id of the row?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have a SQLite DB to which I imported a table from CVS file (using SQLite Database Browser app).
The table consists of two columns.
As far as I understand each row got an id automatically.

What I want now: I need to get a specific row by its content's value (using SELECT command or any other) and get it's ID, then using ID (incrementing) I need to get next row, and so on.

How can I do that?

Comment: Plz elaborate with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That ID column is called [rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid).

It can be read like any other value:

```
SELECT rowid
FROM MyTable
WHERE SomeColumn = 'some value';
```

To get all rows starting from that row:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE rowid >= (SELECT rowid
                FROM MyTable
                WHERE SomeColumn = 'some value')
ORDER BY rowid;
```